# How tosave django output in json file?

Tags: json, django

I want to save django output in .json file.
How should I do this?

I have a geojson data in my django output .
I want to save that output in .json file.
My output is already in json format but only problem is that in django, the output is in arrary format( i.e output is enclosed in close brackets).
So, I can't use that output directly so, I think first saved it in json file then used that.
Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What is "django output" here? A Http Response? And what does it look like exactly, how do you produce it, what is it you need exactly.

Comment: Actually I don't know much about django.

Comment: Yes, the Http response, Actually I want to use that response which is coordinates of polygon to display it on google maps using html.

Comment: So you don't actually want a json file at all, you want a view to return json *data*. What have you tried?

Comment: Actually I have created a view which returns response in json format, but I can't access that response directly via api/url. Problem is that json data enclosed in close brackets. S, I can't access that directly.  How should I use that?

Comment: example:
[
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [ [ 25.774, -80.190],
          [18.466, -66.118],
          [32.321,  -64.757],
          [25.774, -80.190] ] ] } } ]

Comment: This output is in close brackets. so, I can't use this output directly using api.